# What is the difference between pandas dtype vs dtypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For the below pandas code in jupyter I am trying to get the data type information .`tab` in jupyter provides me information that there is two attributes 
It has both `dtype` and `dtypes`

```
import pandas as pd
new_list = [True,False]
new_pd = pd.Series(new_list)
new_pd
```

[image: attributes]

As per the documentation both returns data type information
[image: dtype]

[image: dtypes]

return from both are good and useful

[image: result]

Question is why there is same duplicate attributes .
Which one to be used in which scenario or its a don't care anyone can be used ?

Comment: The biggest difference is that one is a class property, while the other is an instance attribute.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ perfect and that makes some sense now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a [`pd.Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.Series.html) object there is no difference. However, in [`pd.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) objects you only have `dtypes`, which is a series with the data type of each column.

The good thing about this is that when you have a series you can treat it mostly uniformly as a NumPy array and use `.dtype` (which is a property present in every NumPy array) or as a data frame and use `.dtypes` (which is a property present in all Pandas objects). So in principle many functions for NumPy arrays or data frames already work with series out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

You would use `dtypes` with a `DataFrame` to get the `dtype`for each column/Series.